# Активити android

Tags: android

Есть два способа создавать активити экрана. Первое - через xml файл. Второй - программно. Объясните,пожалуйста, когда лучше создавать активити программно и почему? Я новичок в android.

Comment: Во первых, что это за два способа? Во вторых, кто вам сказал, что программно лучше?

Comment: @metalurgus, Я не говорил лучше. Я про то, что не могу найти применение активити, которые было создано программно.

Comment: тогда потрудитесь объяснить, что значит *программно*, а что значит *через Xml файл*

Comment: С xml шаблоном формы и без него.

Comment: @metalurgus, программно, как указано тут http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/activity-theory.php#program , а через xml файл, когда в нем прописываем вручную `Linearlayout`, `TextView` и т.д.

Comment: Создайте экземпляр LinearLayout и дочерние элементы. Добавьте дочерние элементы в child'ы. А в том месте, где берёте форму из ресурсов (R.layout. ... и т.д.) вставляете экземпляр созданного лейаута. Вот и всё.

Comment: Только вставляйте не на место ресурса, а вместо всей конструкции, получающей экземпляр лейаута из ресурса.

Comment: Если есть возможность, всегда лучше создавать разметку через xml

Answer (score 6):

Скорее всего речь идет не о самом активити, а о разметке элементов интерфейса. В большинстве случаев разметка активити создается через `xml` файл, так как в этом случае все параметры отображения и позиционирования во первых, отделяются от кода, во вторых, укомплектованы в более приятном виде. Случаи, когда элементы разметки приходится создавать программно, встречаются гораздо реже. Например, это можно сделать когда необходимо на лету создать какой-нибудь `TextView` и добавить его в активити, но при этом известно, что данный `TextView` будет использоваться не каждый раз, а только в определенных случаях, при определенном действии и т.п.

Программное создание одного `TextView` внутри `RelativeLayout` занимает слишком много места в классе:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1,-1);
layoutParams.setMargins(16,16,16,16);
TextView textView = new TextView(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(-1,-1);
lp.bottomMargin = 10;
lp.topMargin = 10;
lp.leftMargin = 10;
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, R.id.text); 
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.text2);
textView.setTextColor(R.color.md_divider_white);
textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
relativeLayout.addView(textView);
```

Поэтому целесообразно вынести это все в отдельный `xml` файл:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```